# Wordpress Installation in WAMP failed

Tags: php, wordpress

when my installation is completed, i refreshed page and got this error message

**You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page**

any one tell me what is this, how i can solve this..

thanks

Comment: Does it work if you add /index.php to the url?

Comment: Did you login to wordpress?

Comment: This is probably more suited to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: i am following this  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LpPZbscjJk  tutorial and doing every thing, which is in tutorial, but i got this                                                               You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you were not supposed to refresh. 
Start from scratch.
Download wordpress, put the contents in htdocs of wamp folder
Go to

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

Create a new user that wordpress could connect to and assign it a database.
Now start the wordpress installation using the information you made in phpmyadmin.
Sorry if this isn't clear, phpmyadmin can be a little tricky sometimes.